# How to read kanji on the attached photos?

Tags: handwriting, calligraphy

Is anybody able to read these two kanji?

Especially the second one that looks so simple yet I can't decipher the radical...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Those are:

「[寿]{ことぶき}」 (felicitations, longevity, etc.)  and

「[無]{む}」 (nil, naught, etc.)

See [here](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=&p=%E7%84%A1%20%E8%8D%89%E6%9B%B8) for the cursive writing for 「無」.

[image]

EDIT: The following website looks pretty good though I naturally have not checked everything on it.  It gives you an idea of what the cursive looks like for all the basic kanji.  You can check 「無」 there.

http://www013.upp.so-net.ne.jp/santai/santai.htm

[image]

Comment: Wow, I would never of guessed 無 for the second! I thought it looked like 夢 a bit, at least the bottom part (:

Comment: +1 : Anyway, what kind of character recognizer did you use?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian Huh?  I just used my own eyes.

Comment: @Locksleyu Yeah, cursives are very tricky.  I will add a link that I think might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks like

> ## 寿{ことぶき}

Comment: Wow that was indeed super tricky, I would never have guessed... thank you for your help Itrasci and l'électeur !